# Lambda expression not working with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

Im trying to use the IntelliJ IDE to write a JavaFX program, however when the lambda expression is used, I get an error message  followed by a compile error

[original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm1lf.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGQyw.png)

> Overrides method in javafx.event.EventHandler

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {

    window.setTitle("Window Title");
    Button button = new Button("Click me");
    button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello World"));

    }


}
```

[compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ4tH.png)

To specify, it is set up as a JavaFX program, in project structure I have the Project SDK set to 10.0.1 and I have the language level set to 8
Is there something missing that I need in order to use lambda expressions?

Comment: I'm not IntelliJ user, but the error messages seem to suggest something very wrong with your project setting. Mostly likely you need to install a JavaFX project plugin.

Comment: The image of the tooltip does not show an error - it is simply a hint as to which method the lambda overrides. It is shown in red because it is technically a breakpoint hint (i.e., setting a breakpoint on the lambda rather than the whole line).   

It seems strange that the compilation error would be connected to the lambda - are you sure it compiles fine without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the project language level to 10:

[image: language level]

Comment: Why would that be a problem, though? He does not seem to use any language feature not already in 8...

Comment: @Itai compiler options are not correct when Java 10 is used with Java 8 language level. The new module system is not active and compiler reports errors. Another solution is to use JDK 8 for the project.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. I have yet to use the new module system. If that is the case, presumably language level 9 would also work?

Comment: @Itai yes, level 9 will also fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I restarted the project and have the language level set to 10 which seems to have fixed the compile errors (going back to level 8 gives me the original problem). @CrazyCoder

Comment: @TylerJames https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Itai As for the tooltip it is still showing red, is there anything I need to do to make it green such as the one on the start method line? (That is always how I see it tutorials and such)

Comment: @TylerJames it's just the icon in the gutter, it's informational only and you can disable it if you don't like how it looks. If you want this icon to appear in a different color, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

On your application folder build.gradle Add compileOptions inside android:

```
android {
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Indeed under File > Project Structure > modules, the Language level was set to 7 - Diamonds, RM, multi catch.
But since the project is built with maven, the root problem was located in maven pom.xml

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

just set the value to 1.8 and the problem is solved.